# Deploying Laravel apps in LightSpeed Server

Tags: laravel, deployment, server, lightspeed

I have deployed many Laravel apps in Apache Servers. But now I want to know what are the steps to deploy Laravel apps in **LightSpeed** server? What are the pros and cons? I'll be beneficial if someone shares his/her experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Compatibility**
  LiteSpeed Web Server(LSWS) is compatible with most Apache features, e.g. .htaccess, so it's easy for you/developer to migrate laravel apps from Apache.
- **Performance**
  Integrate your app with LSCache Plugin to speed up the page load, check [installation guide][1]
- **GUI**
  We can control listeners, virtual hosts, PHP handlers ..etc through the Web Admin

Let me know if you need more information.
[1]: https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/lsclaravel/installation/